# Edit text in tag to become a new tag

Tags: html, vim, sublimetext, emmet

I have some `html` file has contents which looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td class="col12">3</td>
  <td class="col13"></td>
  <td class="col14">1407664073.4287</td>
  <td class="col15">OUT401-20140810-164753-1407664073.4287.wav</td>
</tr>
```

That is a table with many raws and collumns. And I want to change every `class="col15"`collumn to:

```
<td class="col15"><a href="OUT401-20140810-164753-1407664073.4287.wav">OUT401-20140810-164753-1407664073.4287.wav</a></td>
```

It means changing the text in this collumn to a hyperlink.

How can I do this in an effectively and repetitively way? A macro, or strick?

I use Sublime Text with Vintage, Emmet, and try to record a macro like this:

```
qa
/col15
cit
a<Tab><Esc>p
2l
p
a</
<Esc>
```

The problem is, then I type `q` again to stop recoding macro `a`, and type some command such as n, i,.. Vintage notifies that a another macro is being recoding. So when `a` macro was stopped? And as a result, the `a` macro does not work as I expected.

I aslo tried to do this in Vim with same procedure, but got no better result.

Did I do some wrong step or what? Please give me some advice! Thank you!

Comment: *Must* it be a macro? A regex find/replace can do this in a single file: `CTRL + H`, find: `(col15">)(.+)<`, replace: `$1<a href="$2">$2</a><`.

Answer (score 4):

A possible "vanilla" Vim way:

```
:g/col15/norm cit<a href="^R"">^R"</a>
```

`^R` is obtained with `<C-v><C-r>`.

See `:help :g`, `:help :normal`, `:help registers` and `:help navigation`.

I have no idea if that can be done with ST's vintage mode, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I have tried this in Vim, but it inserts exactly `<a href="^R"">^R"</a>` not `"` for ^R" reg.
In ST's Vintage mode, this makes no sense.

Comment: You didn't really read, did you? "^R is obtained with <C-v><C-r>".

Comment: I'm sorry! I might misunderstood something here.
I also tried <C-v><C-r> instead of ^R, but this cannot help.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing wrong or what you are misunderstanding. My proposed solution does exactly what you ask in Vim in a very straightforward way.